# GCC 4.8 and char16_t streams - bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode, iostream, libstdc++

Is this a libstdc++ bug?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        basic_string<char16_t> str(u"0.0");
        basic_stringstream<char16_t> sstr(str);
        double x = 9;
        sstr >> x;
}
```

Output, under GCC 4.8 Linux x86_64:

```
$ ./main
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Edit** Can someone suggest a way to make this function work under GCC 4.9 without changing its signature:

```
template<typename T>
T fromString(std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>& stream)
{
    T v;
    stream >> v;
    return v;
}
```

Typical use is:

```
std::basic_string<char16_t> string(...);
std::basic_stringstream<char16_t> sstream(string);
double v = fromString<double>(sstream);
```

Comment: The streams are not required to support `char16_t` or `char32_t`, only `char` and `wchar_t`.

Comment: Great.  So, is there a way to make the above work?

Comment: a workaround tip: use utf-8 streams, then convert your string to utf-16 with tools like utfcpp: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: In fact it is just utterly broken, isn't it?  `std::basic_string<char16_t> s; stream >> s;` produces the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard doesn't require implementations to support streams of any type except `char` and `wchar_t`.

[iostreams.limits.pos]

> In the classes of Clause 27, a template parameter with name `charT` represents a member of the set of types containing `char`, `wchar_t`, and any other implementation-defined character types that satisfy the requirements for a character on which any of the iostream components can be instantiated.

Additionally, it doesn't require facets used for extracting integers and floats from streams to work with `char16_t` either:

[category.numeric]

> All specifications of member functions for `num_put` and `num_get` in the subclauses of 22.4.2 only apply to the specializations required in Tables 81 and 82 (22.3.1.1.1), namely `num_get<char>`, `num_get<wchar_t>`, `num_get<C, InputIterator>`, `num_put<char>`, `num_put<wchar_t>`, and `num_put<C,OutputIterator>`.

where `C`:

> A template parameter with name `C` represents the set of types containing
>   `char`, `wchar_t`, and any other implementation-defined character types that satisfy the requirements for a character on which any of the iostream components can be instantiated.

The standard only requires that `char_traits` (and so `basic_string`) and `codecvt` work correctly for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

So to make your function work you would basically need to define specializations of all the missing pieces that the library doesn't provide.