# Canot read char8_t from basic_stringstream<char8_t>

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, gcc9

I'm simply trying `stringstream` in UTF-8:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
int main()
{
    std::basic_stringstream<char8_t> ss(u8"hello");
    char8_t c;
    std::cout << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::goodbit) << " " << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::badbit) << " "
            << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::failbit) << " " << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::eofbit) << "\n";
    ss >> c;
    std::cout << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::goodbit) << " " << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::badbit) << " "
            << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::failbit) << " " << (ss.rdstate() & std::ios_base::eofbit) << "\n";
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile using:

```
g++-9 -std=c++2a -g -o bin/test test/test.cpp
```

The result on screen is:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 4 0
0
```

It seems that something goes wrong when reading `c`, but I don't know how to correct it. Please help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually an old issue not specific to support for `char8_t`.  The same issue occurs with `char16_t` or `char32_t` in C++11 and newer.  The following gcc bug report has a similar test case.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88508

The issue is also discussed at the following:

- [GCC 4.8 and char16_t streams - bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294129/gcc-4-8-and-char16-t-streams-bug)
- [Why does `std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>` not work in c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315675/why-does-stdbasic-ifstreamchar16-t-not-work-in-c11)
- http://gcc.1065356.n8.nabble.com/UTF-16-streams-td1117792.html

The issue is that gcc does not implicitly imbue the global locale with facets for `ctype<char8_t>`, `ctype<char16_t>`, or `ctype<char32_t>`.  When attempting to perform an operation that requires one of these facets, a `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown from `std::__check_facet` (which is subsequently silently swallowed by the IOS sentry object created for the character extraction operator and which then sets `badbit` and `failbit`).

The C++ standard only requires that `ctype<char>` and `ctype<wchar_t>` be provided.  See [[locale.category]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/locale.category#2).